# Shared library, makefile. Library path

Tags: c++

Im trying to link my program to the shared library. Im using a makefile to compile. It looks like this: `

```
make: sms_out.cpp SMSDispatch.cpp SMSDispatch.h
      g++ -c -fPIC SMSDispatch.cpp -o SMSDispatch.o
      g++ -shared SMSDispatch.o -o libSMSDispatch.so
`     g++ sms_out.cpp -L. -lSMSDispatch -o sms_out
```

It works fine if I run the program in the command window with:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="." ./sms_out
```

But I want to run it with just `./sms_out`, can someone help me?
Tried to add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` to the makefile, but that didnt work, just got the error " error while loading shared libraries: libSMSDispatch.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when I try to run the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the directory where the `.so` file exists to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/dir/containing/sharedobject
```

A utility you may find useful is `ldd`, which prints the shared library dependencies. For example:

```
    $ ldd /bin/ls
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff819ff000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007fc0d3f67000)
        libselinux.so.1 => /lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007fc0d3d4a000)
        libacl.so.1 => /lib64/libacl.so.1 (0x00007fc0d3b42000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc0d37e9000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc0d35cd000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc0d4170000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc0d33c9000)
        libattr.so.1 => /lib64/libattr.so.1 (0x00007fc0d31c4000)
```

If shared objects are not locatable a string *not found*, or similar, is displayed instead of the path to the shared object being used.

Comment: I want to tell the running pogram that the library it is looking for is in the folder Im in, also ".", It works fine with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="." ./sms_out`, or with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` before running the program. But if I try to add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` to the makefile it doesnt work when I try to run the program after calling makefile. Do you know why?

Comment: Check the value of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` after you run the makefile: you can't `export` variables like that, the `export` will only affect the process running the script. I don't know of a way to modify an environment variable from a makefile (that is not to say a mechanism does not exist, I just don't know of one). If you had a script that contained `export` statements you could change the environment by invoking it like: `$ . ./myexport.sh`

Comment: ok but can I put the export statement into the file I want to run(sms_out.cpp)? btw the value of LD_LIBRARY_PATH is blank after I run the makefile, and I think it was blank before I run it too

Comment: No, the library path would have to be set prior to the execution of `sms_out`. Is there a reason you dislike setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from the command-line?

Comment: No just thought it would look better, be easier. Thank you

Comment: You could generate a static library `.a` instead of a shared and just statically link it into you binary, avoiding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` modification. I know this question was specific to shared objects but just thought I would mention it.

Answer (score 3):

Another option - provide -rpath options to linker to inform your binary where else search for dynamic objects.

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath=<path to .so> -o <your binary here> <cpp file name>.cpp
```